# Bootstrapping a Groovy install?

Tags: ros, catkin-pkg, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get a groovy install running, from scratch / source, and I have found a couple of tutorials for starting from catkin, but none of them work.   I have tried these on Ubuntu precise, and also just from source on Debian sid.

I've tried:

http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/underlay.html - There is no `python-catkin-pkg` package that I can find on Ubuntu or in the package build repository, and if I ignore it, I get an error later in the process about not finding a python module named `catkin_pkg.package`.

After some help finding catkin_pkg (http://github.com/ros-infastructure/catkin_pkg) and installing it, I run into a second issue with the instructions, when I'm running `cmake ../src`, it ends with this error:

```
CMake Error at /home/jamuraa/tmp/testing/groovy-install/build/buildspace/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "std_msgs" with any
  of the following names:

    std_msgsConfig.cmake
    std_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "std_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "std_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "std_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

This looks like it's trying to find the std_msgs package before it has discovered it, but after looking around for a while, I don't quite know enough about catkin internals to figure out what is causing it.

- http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/ - This seems aimed toward fuerte (obvious from the url), but it doesn't work just updating it for groovy.

**Is there a document somewhere for how to bootstrap a Groovy Galapagos ROS install for testing / development?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44606/bootstrapping-a-groovy-install?/) by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this link can help:
https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/175

The deb can be downloaded and installed like this:

```
$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/c/catkinpkg/python-catkin-pkg_0.1.0-1_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i python-catkin-pkg_0.1.0-1_all.deb
```

I ended up downloading the sources and installing manually using

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

But I needed an install from source anyway.

EDIT:
What you describe could be a bug in the dependencies. catkin needs to create std_msgsConfig.cmake before using it, so if some package (rosmaster) uses std_sgs in the CMakeLists.txt, but does not declare that dependency in the package.xml, this error would occur. This occurs for ros_comm/rosmaster.
Since catkin is very much in flux right now, you can either report this or wait a day until it got fixed.

A simple update (rosws update -j8 in src) could do the trick. As I said, this is very much in flux right now, as the catkin design has been changed a lot, and a lot of packages need to be migrated.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on 2012-09-27**:
Thanks for this informed explanation.  If I wanted to help fix the dependency problem, could I branch and send pull requests to places somehow, or is it more recommended at this point to just wait until the dust settles a little more?